# Extract last two number of IP in ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I need some help coming up with a very simple way of extracting the last two numbers from an IP address in ansible. My playbook currently looks like this

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - name: install dns resolver
     yum: name=python-dns

   - debug: msg={{ lookup('dig','google.com.') }}
```

Running this playbook yields the following

```
TASK [install dns resolver] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
"msg": "172.217.7.142"
```

Is there a way in ansible to just return the last two numbers of that IP? i.e.42

I actually have to embed this in a template which ultimately would have a format like so:

```
last_two_numbers_of_IP={{ lookup('dig','google.com.') }}
```

Output in template should look like so:

```
 last_two_numbers_of_IP=42
```

Comment: What should it return if the address was `10.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the last octet and then last two chars of last octet. If the last octet has only one number, it will return just that number.

```
  vars:
    ip: 192.168.1.123

  tasks:
   - name: install dns resolver
     debug: msg={{ ip.split('.')[-1][-2:] }}
```

**Output**

```
TASK [install dns resolver] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "23"
}
```

Comment: Thanks helloV. I edited the initial question to leverage the answer you provided.